# select within uncached block is returning a stale object

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing something like the following.

```
class SomeModel
   def crazy
      sm = SomeModel.where(:id => 1).first
      sleep(30)
      # after 15 seconds we update the record manually
      sm = SomeModel.uncached {SomeModel.where(:id => 1).first}
      begin
         sm.field = 'value'
         sm.save
      rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError => e
         puts 'happening'
      end
   end
end
```

When this model method is called from a controller, as the uncached select is performed after the manual update, I should not be getting a stale object but testing it says otherwise. Am I misunderstanding something? I am using Rails 3.0.5 with Mysql.

Comment: What do you see in the server log? Do you see a CACHE query for after 30 seconds?

Comment: No, I do not see any CACHE queries in the server logs.